# ¿Como puedo plotear un espectograma usando la funcion mlab.specgram() y acomodar los ejes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy intentado aprender a realizar espectogramas y encontré que matplot.mlab.specgram() permite realizar la conversión a tiempo-frecuencia. Sin embargo, pese a que ya me leí la documentación y entiendo su funcionamiento (eso creo), no consigo comprender los resultados que arroja. Intenté graficarlos pero los resultados no concuerdan con lo que yo espero de acuerdo a la teoría.

Realice una pequeña señal de prueba:

```
time = np.linspace(0,10,40*10)

s1 = np.sin(20*np.pi*time)
[array2d, fre, times] = mlab.specgram(s1,NFFT=int(10),Fs=80,window=mlab.window_hanning(np.ones(int(10))),
                        noverlap=int(5))
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
plt.imshow(array2d)
```

lo cual me grafica lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando imprimo los resultados de frecuencia y timpo, obtengo esto:

```
 print(times)
 out[1]: [0.0625 0.125  0.1875 0.25   0.3125 0.375  0.4375 0.5    0.5625 0.625 0.6875 0.75   0.8125 0.875  0.9375 1.     1.0625 1.125  1.1875 1.25
 1.3125 1.375  1.4375 1.5    1.5625 1.625  1.6875 1.75   1.8125 1.875
 1.9375 2.     2.0625 2.125  2.1875 2.25   2.3125 2.375  2.4375 2.5
 2.5625 2.625  2.6875 2.75   2.8125 2.875  2.9375 3.     3.0625 3.125
 3.1875 3.25   3.3125 3.375  3.4375 3.5    3.5625 3.625  3.6875 3.75
 3.8125 3.875  3.9375 4.     4.0625 4.125  4.1875 4.25   4.3125 4.375
 4.4375 4.5    4.5625 4.625  4.6875 4.75   4.8125 4.875  4.9375]
 print(fre)
 out[2]: [ 0.  8. 16. 24. 32. 40.]
```

Se supone que en el grafico deberia obtener, una respuesta maxima en 20Hz pero no comprendo los ejes Y y X. Además, no entiendo como se interpreta el vector de `freq` y `times`. Alguien me podría, por favor, ayudar a comprender y adaptar el grafico? es para usarlo en un proyecto academico donde tengo que hacer un fingerprint para cada archivo de audio y este grafico debe ir en el reporte. Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

mira este ejemplo:

```
# import the libraries

import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as np


# Define the list of frequencies
frequencies         = np.arange(5,105,5)

# Sampling Frequency
samplingFrequency   = 400

# Create two ndarrays
s1 = np.empty([0]) # For samples
s2 = np.empty([0]) # For signal


# Start Value of the sample
start   = 1 

# Stop Value of the sample
stop    = samplingFrequency+1


for frequency in frequencies:
    sub1 = np.arange(start, stop, 1)

    # Signal - Sine wave with varying frequency + Noise
    sub2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*sub1*frequency*1/samplingFrequency)+np.random.randn(len(sub1))

    s1      = np.append(s1, sub1)
    s2      = np.append(s2, sub2)

    start   = stop+1
    stop    = start+samplingFrequency

# Plot the signal
plot.subplot(211)
plot.plot(s1,s2)
plot.xlabel('Sample')
plot.ylabel('Amplitude')


# Plot the spectrogram

plot.subplot(212)
powerSpectrum, freqenciesFound, time, imageAxis = plot.specgram(s2, Fs=samplingFrequency)
plot.xlabel('Time')
plot.ylabel('Frequency')

plot.show()
```